# why my own bzero function is different original one?

Tags: c

```
void    ft_bzero(void *s, size_t n)
{
    char    *str;
    size_t  i = 0;

    str = (char *)s;
    while (i <= n)
    {
        str[i] = 0;
        i++;
    }
    return ;
}
```

```
int main(void)
{
    char    str[3] = {"abc"};

    ft_bzero(str, 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%c", str[i]);

    return (0);
}
```

my code is this and output is none.
but, original bzero is output a 'c'.

why is it different?

I don't know why my own function working like that...

Comment: `while (i <= n)` -> `while (i < n)`. You did one more iteration than required.

Comment: In addition, don't split declaration and initialisation of variables; use `for` instead of `while` where it makes sense (it makes sense here). Don't use `return;` if you don't need to exit early. Don't perform explicit casts to and from `void*`. Taken all this together cuts your code down to less than half its current length, and makes it clearer.

Comment: `void  ft_bzero(void *s, size_t n)  { char* p= (char*)s;  size_t i; for(i = 0; i < n; i++) { *p = '\0'; ++p;  } }`  what the problem? BTW compiler will detect you function as the bzero during optimization, and more likely replace such function body with call to library bzero written on assembly. This naive implementation not effective at all. Try not to reinvent the wheal, use library function or compiler intrinsic (i.e. __builtin_bzero) where possible.

Comment: `char    str[3] = {"abc"};` is too short for the characters + null terminator, so is not a valid string.

Comment: I appreciate your comments! thanks all!!

Comment: and, @KonradRudolph " Don't perform explicit casts to and from void*. " is write the code like "char *str = s;" ?

Comment: @Whycodedoesn'tworking Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to zero n characters in a string, your indices will be 0..n-1.
Therefore you need to change:

```
while (i <= n)
```

To:

```
while (i < n)
```

BTW Searching for `ft_bzero` I found this: [`ft_bzero` implementation from github](https://github.com/mantal/libft/blob/master/ft_bzero.c).
You can compare your implementation with it.

Comment: There's no sensible reason why this wasn't implemented with a `for` loop.